Fetch all data with single query in Django
How to fetch all child related objects in a single query in Django?
For example we have 3 models:
class Parent(models.Model):
  ...

class Child(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

class SubChild(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Child)

I want to fetch all the data in a single query like this:
select * from parent p join child c on c.parent_id = p.id join subchild sc on sc.parent_id = c.id

How I could perform this using Django ORM? What if I will have multiple child models? In SQL I just add more joins, but how I could do it in Django?
Now I have few seconds delay when load everything recursively with multiple queries. The prefetch_related method does not help, I mean
qs = Parent.objects.all().prefetch_related('child').prefetch_related('child__subchild')

for parent in qs:
  # here I need to access parent.childs.all() and child.subchild.all() without new queries


You can't do that as prefetch_related will perform extra SQL queries and perform the "join" in Python. This is by design. What you can do is to get all SubChild instances, and select_related the parent and parent__parent accessors. Obviously you will also have to change your loop logic too.

@Selcuk What if I will have multiple child models? Not only Child -> SubChild, but also Child2 -> SubChild2? Completely impossible?

I don't know of a way to accomplish that in a single query using the ORM, at least not without raw SQL.

Actually parent.childs.all() won't cause a query because you have a prefetch_related for that relation. In the code you've shown there would only be 3 queries regardless of the number of Parent and Child objects.

@AbdulAzizBarkat Yes, you're right. In my case Django made extra queries because I had parent.childs.all().order_by('some_field')

You've got an answer for the first part of your question, and I wanted to address the second part - how can we prefetch data with multiple child models.
We can get values lists, if not objects itself. For example, we have models like these - parent class, two children classes with foreign keys to it and their children classes with foreign keys respectively:
class Parent(models.Model):
  name = models.TextField()

class Child1(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.TextField()

class SubChild1(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Child1, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.TextField()

class Child2(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.TextField()

class SubChild2(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey(Child2, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  name = models.TextField()

Using these models, we can get values lists of subchildren with needed columns, including parent and parent of parent columns, then union these values lists - it creates one query with inner joins. So this code
 grandchildren1 = SubChild1.objects.all().values_list(
     'id', 'name', 'parent__name', 'parent__parent__name'
     ).prefetch_related('parent').prefetch_related('parent')
 grandchildren2 = SubChild2.objects.all().values_list(
     'id', 'name', 'parent__name', 'parent__parent__name'
     ).prefetch_related('parent').prefetch_related('parent')
 grandchildren = grandchildren1.union(grandchildren2)

results in this single query:
SELECT "app_subchild1"."id" AS "col1", 
     "app_subchild1"."name" AS "col2", 
     "app_child1"."name" AS "col3", 
     "app_parent"."name" AS "col4" 
 FROM "app_subchild1" 
 INNER JOIN "app_child1" ON (
     "app_subchild1"."parent_id" = "app_child1"."id"
 ) 
 INNER JOIN "app_parent" ON (
     "app_child1"."parent_id" = "app_parent"."id"
 ) 
 UNION 
 SELECT "app_subchild2"."id" AS "col1", 
     "app_subchild2"."name" AS "col2", 
     "app_child2"."name" AS "col3", 
     "app_parent"."name" AS "col4" 
 FROM "app_subchild2" 
 INNER JOIN "app_child2" ON (
     "app_subchild2"."parent_id" = "app_child2"."id"
 ) 
 INNER JOIN "app_parent" ON (
     "app_child2"."parent_id" = "app_parent"."id"
 )

If you don't need the objects of grandchildren, but their data, you could use this approach.
We also can prefetch both child objects and their chidlren too, then union both querysets - meaning, we won't get error, but it doesn't work as intended: first queryset's prefetch works, second silently doesn't. This queryset:
qs = (Parent.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related('child1_set')
    .prefetch_related('child1_set__subchild1_set')
    .union(
    Parent.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related('child2_set')
    .prefetch_related('child2_set__subchild2_set')
    )) 

results in these queries:
'SELECT "app_parent"."id", "app_parent"."name" 
 FROM "app_parent"'

'SELECT "app_child1"."id", "app_child1"."parent_id", "app_child1"."name" 
 FROM "app_child1" 
 WHERE "app_child1"."parent_id" IN (1, 2, 3)'

'SELECT "app_subchild1"."id", "app_subchild1"."parent_id", "app_subchild1"."name" 
 FROM "app_subchild1" 
 WHERE "app_subchild1"."parent_id" IN (1, 2, 3)'

'SELECT "app_child2"."id", "app_child2"."parent_id", "app_child2"."name" 
 FROM "app_child2" 
 WHERE "app_child2"."parent_id" = 1'

'SELECT "app_child2"."id", "app_child2"."parent_id", "app_child2"."name"
 FROM "app_child2" 
 WHERE "app_child2"."parent_id" = 2'

'SELECT "app_child2"."id", "app_child2"."parent_id", "app_child2"."name"
 FROM "app_child2" 
 WHERE "app_child2"."parent_id" = 3'

'SELECT "app_subchild2"."id", "app_subchild2"."parent_id", "app_subchild2"."name" 
 FROM "app_subchild2" 
 WHERE "app_subchild2"."parent_id" = 1'

'SELECT "app_subchild2"."id", "app_subchild2"."parent_id", "app_subchild2"."name" 
 FROM "app_subchild2" 
 WHERE "app_subchild2"."parent_id" = 2'

It seems to be not desired behaviour, as stated here, and could be fixed in future.
